# Sum unicode values of String without API functions, except String.length

Tags: java, unicode

I have been instructed to write an application summing the Unicode values of a String, without the use of any Java API's except `.length`.

So basically I have to write the method below without the use of the `codePointAt` method. I can however write my own utilities, I just have no idea how to do this.

Can someone help me out?

```
public static int addChars(String s) {
  int sum = 0;
  int charCount = s.length();

  for(int i=0;i<charCount;i++){
     sum += s.codePointAt(i);
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Consult the spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode (I assume you can use charAt, or toCharArray.)

Comment: You have to be able to use *some* API functions - there's no other way to access the data in a String.

Comment: the only API methods I can use are length, chatAt, and substring.

Comment: I realize that this is probably homework, but why in the world would anyone want to do this?

Comment: FWIW, the example you give using `codePointAt` is wrong. Try it with the string `"\uD83C\uDF4C"`, which is just one character, the U+1F34C [BANANA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f34c/index.htm) character. The sum should be 0x1f34c (127820 in decimal). (so, make sure your alternative implementation does not make the same mistakes)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This sounds like homework to me, so rather than give you code, I'll give you some hints.

1. `char`s in Java are based on Unicode UTF-16 codes.  A `char` is 16 bits long.
2. `short` is also 16 bits, and `int` is 32 bits.
3. You can cast between primitive types trivially, assuming that they're the same length, or that the thing you're casting *into* is longer (in bits) than what you're casting *from*.
4. Some Unicode characters don't fit in a single Java `char`.  When this happens, you need to combine two consecutive `char` (16-bit) values into a single `int` (32-bit).  (Note:  See the documentation on the [`Character` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) for how to tell if you've got one of those situations -- it has to do with the numeric range that the character code is in).  The `char`s you'll get in these situations are called *surrogates* (useful hint to guide you in the linked documentation).

Comment: This is of course the answer. @DillonMonroe You don't even need to explicitly cast a char to an int since Java automatically promotes them. You can just sum them.

Comment: thanks guys, and yeah, this is homework. My teacher is making write all the utilities for our applications just so we really understand them.

Comment: Fair enough.  If this answer helped you don't forget to upvote / accept it.

Comment: You can't just take chars and sum them.  If there is a 32-bit code in the mix that will fail.  One must examine the character stream for Unicode escape characters and handle them appropriately.

Comment: @HotLicks while true, the exercise is so silly in the first place (what *possible* use is there in summing up character codes at all?) than I expect the student is expected to overlook that detail.  Further, the student has been given very few allowed calls into the API.  He's not allowed `codePointAt` on `String`, so I'd wager he's probably not allowed any of the codepoint methods on `Character`, either, which doesn't leave many options.

Comment: If the student was told specifically that he could not use codePointAt then he may be "expected" to overlook that detail, but if he does he's unlikely to get a very good grade.  The reference I posted above provides some details on Unicode escape processing, and there's plenty more on the web.  It's not difficult, and I don't doubt that SOME students in his class will figure it out and get good grades as a result.

Comment: There's no need to call the methods of Character to find the surrogates -- they're well defined in the Unicode standard and easy to test for.

Comment: You know, you're right.  I should really stop trying to do this before coffee.  Answer updated.